# separate character string at first digit with "*" in the string

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

This is an easy one I think but I cannot see what I'm missing. I want to split the string at the first digit. Works great until there is a non-alphanumeric symbol in the string. Help!

Works:

```
pet<-c("Dog 100","Cat? 340")
df<-as.data.frame(pet)
df_split<-separate(df, pet, into = c("Animal", "Total"), sep = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\s*(?=[0-9])")
```

The first line works great but the second line does not split. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you meant `?` or `*`.  Your example is not matching with the description

Comment: Try `separate(df, pet, into = c("Animal", "Total"), sep = "(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\W*(?=[0-9])")`

Comment: I would simply do `library(tidyverse); library(stringr); str_split_fixed(df$pet, "(?=[0-9])",2) %>% trimws()`

Comment: Please let know of the actual specifications: what kind of chars do you expect to split with? If there can be any non-alphanumeric char(s), you should replace `\\s*` in your pattern with `\\W`, or even better with `[\\W_]`, or `[^[:alnum:]]`. However, you need to clarify before we can jump to conclusions.

Comment: Yes, I did mean "?". I changed my example but then didn't change the question! Thanks or all the feedback. I quite simply want to split the string at the first number regardless of what comes before it. So no matter what the string is, i want to split it right before the first digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that **for the current scenario**, it is enough to split with 1+ whitespaces that are followed with 1+ digits to the end of the string:

```
> separate(df, pet, into = c("Animal", "Total"), sep = "\\s+(?=[0-9]+$)")
## =>  Animal Total
## =>    1    Dog   100
## =>    2   Cat?   340
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Alsef/1).

However, **in a general case**, it is much easier to use `tidyr::extract` here since the pattern you need will be miuch simpler:

```
^(\D*?)\s*(\d.*)
```

Note that if your strings can have newlines, you will need to prepend the pattern with `(?s)`, a so-called DOTALL modifier that allows `.` to match line break chars in an ICU pattern.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Alsef/2).

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(\D*?)` - Group 1 (here, `Animal` column): any 0+ non-digit symbols, as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `(\d.*)` - Group 2 (here, `Total` column): a digit followed with any 0+ chars (other than line break chars if `(?s)` is not used), as many as possible (`*` is a greedy quantifier).

R code snippet:

```
library(tidyr)
df_split<-extract(df, pet, into = c("Animal", "Total"), regex="(\\D*)(\\d.*)")
df_split
# =>   Animal Total
# => 1   Dog    100
# => 2  Cat?    340
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `read.table` from `base R`

```
read.table(text = sub("?", "", df$pet, fixed = TRUE), header = FALSE,
  col.names = c("Animal", "Total"))
#    Animal Total
#1    Dog   100
#2    Cat   340
```